# How can I access strings in `strings.xml` from a Recycler Adapter class using `getString()` in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I need to access strings in `strings.xml` from a custom Recycler Adapter class but I am getting an error message as described. Here is my Kotlin Recycler Adapter class with the method `onBindViewHolder()` where I try to access the strings with placeholders `miles` and `poundSign`:

```
import android.content.res.Resources
import android.provider.Settings.Global.getString
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import java.text.DecimalFormat

class SiteAdapter(
    private val mainActivity: CountiesActivity,
    private val siteList: List<Site>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SiteAdapter.ListItemHolder>() {

    inner class ListItemHolder(view: View):
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view),
        View.OnClickListener {

        internal var name = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.textViewSiteName) as TextView

        internal var distance = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.textViewSiteDistance) as TextView

        internal var price = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.textViewSitePrice) as TextView

        init {

            view.isClickable = true
            view.setOnClickListener(this)

        }

        override fun onClick(view: View) {

            mainActivity.showDetails(adapterPosition)

        }

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ListItemHolder {

        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.recycler_list_item, parent, false)

        return ListItemHolder(itemView)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        if (siteList != null) {
            return siteList.size
        }
        // error
        return -1

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListItemHolder, position: Int) {

        val site = siteList[position]

        holder.name.text = site.name
        holder.distance.text = site.distance.toString() + Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.miles)
        val decimalFormatter = DecimalFormat("#,###.00")
        holder.price.text = Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.poundSign) + decimalFormatter.format(site.price).toString()

    }


}
```

Here is my `strings.xml` file:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">GoSiteUK</string>
    <string name="title_england">England</string>
    <string name="title_scotland">Scotland</string>
    <string name="title_wales">Wales</string>
    <string name="title_nireland">N.Ireland</string>
    <string name="helpInstructions">\n\n\n\n\n\nSelect from the available countries at the bottom of the screen to display a list of
        counties for that country. Then select a county for which you wish to see campsites, caravan sites or motorhome sites. Select
    a particular site that you wish to travel to and you will be presented with more information about the site. Click on \"Take Me
    Here\" and a map will be displayed with navigation instructions and route information to follow to take you to that selected
    site.\n\nFor support contact:\n\nriverstonetechuk@gmail.com\n</string>
    <string name="help">Help</string>
    <string name="title_counties">--- Counties ---</string>
    <string name="title_regions">--- Regions ---</string>
    <string name="title_areas">--- Areas ---</string>
    <string name="title_districts">--- Districts ---</string>

    <string name="name">Name:</string>
    <string name="distance">Distance:</string>
    <string name="price">Price:</string>
    <string name="miles"> miles</string>
    <string name="poundSign">£</string>
</resources>
```

The error messages are shown below:

```
-01-28 16:09:25.229 16740-16740/com.riverstonetech.gositeuk W/ResourceType: No known package when getting value for resource number 0x7f0f0049
2020-01-28 16:09:25.230 16740-16740/com.riverstonetech.gositeuk D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-01-28 16:09:25.231 16740-16740/com.riverstonetech.gositeuk E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.riverstonetech.gositeuk, PID: 16740
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0f0049
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:335)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:381)
```

Any solutions to solve this greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that the problem is cause because of the access of

```
Resources.getSystem()
```

I would strongly suggest to not do that.

Suggestion from my side: Make the view in ListItemHolder as accessible field like this

```
inner class ListItemHolder(val view: View)
```

And then you can access the string resources via that view:

```
holder.price.text = holder.view.context.getString(R.string.poundSign) + decimalFormatter.format(site.price).toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the String file of the Android system not you own String.xml of your application !

In fact if you want to access to a known Android resource value you have to use it this way : `Resources.getSystem().getString(android.R.string.cancel)`

Otherwise if you want to access your own String resource file you must call the function `getResources()` from a context. For instance : `context.getResources().getString(R.string.poundSign);`

If the `CountiesActivity` is an `Activity` the you could call `mainActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.whatever);`

Since the garbage collector could destroy your activity sometimes, a good way to store an Activity context is to store a `WeakReferences` of it. It prevent to have loop references over your context application and memory leak. Take a look to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference).

I hope it helps and feel free to ask question if it is not clear.
Have fun !

Comment: Thanks @GuillaumeMonrolin.